# Table Normalization (Parse comma separated fields into individual records)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a table like this:

**Device**

```
DeviceId   Parts

1          Part1, Part2, Part3
2          Part2, Part3, Part4
3          Part1
```

I would like to create a table 'Parts', export data from Parts column to the new table. I will drop the Parts column after that

Expected result

**Parts**

```
PartId PartName

  1      Part1
  2      Part2
  3      Part3
  4      Part4
```

**DevicePart**

```
DeviceId PartId

  1      1
  1      2
  1      3
  2      2
  2      3
  2      4
  3      1
```

Can I do this in SQL Server 2008 without using cursors?

Comment: What have you tried so far. A hint all you need here is a table with partID(Int, Identity(1,1)),partname and insert into that with a select distinct..After that one Join will get you second table..

Comment: I have tried cursors so far but I don't like the solution and I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-- Setup:

```
declare @Device table(DeviceId int primary key, Parts varchar(1000))
declare @Part table(PartId int identity(1,1) primary key, PartName varchar(100))
declare @DevicePart table(DeviceId int, PartId int)

insert @Device
values
    (1, 'Part1, Part2, Part3'),
    (2, 'Part2, Part3, Part4'),
    (3, 'Part1')
```

--Script:

```
declare @DevicePartTemp table(DeviceId int, PartName varchar(100))

insert @DevicePartTemp
select DeviceId, ltrim(x.value('.', 'varchar(100)'))
from
(
    select DeviceId, cast('<x>' + replace(Parts, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml) XmlColumn
    from @Device
)tt
cross apply
    XmlColumn.nodes('x') as Nodes(x)


insert @Part
select distinct PartName
from @DevicePartTemp

insert @DevicePart
select tmp.DeviceId, prt.PartId
from @DevicePartTemp tmp 
    join @Part prt on
        prt.PartName = tmp.PartName
```

-- Result:

```
select *
from @Part

PartId      PartName
----------- ---------
1           Part1
2           Part2
3           Part3
4           Part4


select *
from @DevicePart

DeviceId    PartId
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           2
2           3
2           4
3           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Tally table to accomplish this without a cursor.

Follow the instructions to create a tally table here: [Tally Tables by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

This script will put the table into your Temp database, so you probably want to change the "Use DB" statement

Then you can run the script below to insert a breakdown of Devices and Parts into a temp table. You should then be able to join on your part table by the part name (to get the ID) and insert into your new DevicePart table.

```
select *, 
--substring(d.parts, 1, t.n)
substring(d.parts, t.n, charindex(', ', d.parts + ', ',t.n) - t.n) 'Part'
into #devicesparts
from device d
cross join tally t
where t.n < (select max(len(parts))+ 1 from device)
and substring(', ' + d.parts, t.n, 1) = ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [fn_Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to create a table variable from the comma separated values.
You can then use this to drive your insert.

EDIT: Actually, I think you may still need a cursor. Leaving this answer incase fn_Split helps.

Comment: Lordy, please don't use THAT function.  It uses an mTVF and a WHILE loop.  It's one of the slowest splitters available.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a maximum number of parts per device then, yes, it can be done without a cursor, but this is quite complex.

Essentially, create a table (or view or subquery) that has a DeviceID and one PartID column for each possible index in the PartID string. This can be accomplished by making the PartID columns calculated columns using fn_split or another method of your choice. From there you do a multiple self-UNION of this table, with one table in the self-UNION for each PartID column. Each table in the self-UNION has only one of the PartID columns included in the select list of the query for the table.