# unserialize() value of database and putting it in json_encode after foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization, json, denormalized

I insert in database values (array) `$row->units` with use function `serialize()`=>`[$row->units]`, how can echo they with `unserialize()` in `json_encode` with `$row->name`? (return send for ajax call in jQuery)

Columns in database:

> $row->units =>
>   `a:6:{i:0;s:15:"Coffee";i:1;s:14:"Satellite";i:2;s:11:"Game
>   Notes";i:3;s:14:"Internet";i:4;s:10:"Pool";i:5;s:0:"";}`
>
> $row->name=> `George Kurdahi`

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM arraha WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name asc");

$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $data[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'units' => unserialize($row->units)); // Line 22
}
return json_encode($data)
```

The error for code above is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 277 of
>   281 bytes
>
> Filename: model.php
>
> Line Number: 22

Comment: Either your serialize failed, the column isn't big enough to hold the data, or some charset issue. Could you show us the string _before_ you unserialize, and a `SHOW CREATE TABLE arraha`  output?

Comment: Edited my posts. Please see again.

Comment: Why are you putting serialized values in an RDBMS?

Comment: This is [bad design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation). It *will* [come back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201158/join-tables-with-comma-values) [to haunt you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212282/is-it-possible-to-query-a-comma-separated-column-for-a-specific-value) in the future.

Comment: What is your suggestion in my code?

Comment: Consider using BINARY/VARBINARY/BLOB columns instead of CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT columns.

Comment: Create another table, say `arraha_units`, with two fields, say `arraha_id` (FK to your PK in `arraha`) and `unit` (and perhaps its own PK as well). Get rid of the `units` column in `arraha`. Now insert rows like `(1, 'Coffee')`, `(1, 'Satellite')` into this new table.

Comment: Now you can get all your units for id=1 by using: `SELECT unit FROM arraha_units WHERE arraha_id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with character encoding:

```
s:15:"Coffee"
```

15 means length in bytes. So you have to translate encoding of data fetched from DB into encoding that was used with serialize()

You can use json_encode instead of serialize:

```
$arr = array('Coffee', 'Satellite', /*...*/);
$row->units = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: This is true, and your serialized column _should not have a character set_. You're not storing 'textual' data as far as serialized strings are concerned. Consider using  BINARY/VARBINARY/BLOB columns instead of CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT columns.

Comment: @George If you don't want to change your application design either change the column type in DB or replace serialize with json_encode. Or you can store your array as XML document. Then you can query it with [ExtractValue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html) MySQL function

Comment: @Wrikken That's right. i used of `VARCHAR`. Which one do I use (`BINARY` or `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`) ?

Comment: @ExtractValue how is use of `json_encode`, did you can give a example of my code in first post?

Comment: @George Kurdahi: type depends on need. How much data do you need to enter there? (And although NullUserException's comment is somewhat premature because he doesn't know your data yet, database normalization _could_ be a better solution).