# Dynamically replace data in a oracle field with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a varchar column test_data with data in csv format in a table temp_table1.
Example Data >

```
,1,2,3,
,14,18,
,3,4,
```

for each numerical there is a mapping string like 1="ABC",2="XYX" , 3="PQR" on **another** 
database mapping table temp_table2

Is there any way to display the data by replacing each numerical with its mapping using a
single sql query??

eg: `**,1,2,3**, as **ABC,XYZ,PQR**`

I have tried using decode,regexp_replace but cannot find the solution.

Database : Oracle 11g.

Comment: Do ***not*** store comma separated values in a single column. Normalize your model and your problem is reduced to a simple (and efficient) `JOIN` operation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But this field is used in this way at many places. Is there any way to replace by using SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Reverse GROUP\_CONCAT" in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, albeit a bit yucky.  You really should use a junction table and fix the database structure, if you have any control over this.

The method is to expand the data using an inefficient join and then use `listagg()` to bring the results back together.  The result is something like this:

```
select td.id, listagg(tt.val, ',') within group (order by td.id)
from test_data td left join
     temp_table2 tt
     on td.col like '%,' || tt.col || '%,'
group by td.id;
```