# How can I find the most frequently mentioned hashtags in a MySQL column?

Tags: php, mysql, hashtag

My database has a table messages with 3 fields: 'messageid',`messagetext (varchar)`, `dateposted (datetime)`

I want to store a bunch of messages in the field `messagetext` along with their respective date of posting in the field `dateposted`. A lot of these messages will have `hashtags` in them.

Then, using PHP and MySQL I want to find out which hashtags are the top 5 most frequently mentioned `hashtags` in messages posted in the past week.

How can I do this? I'd really appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: By far the easiest way would be to parse the hashtags at the time of insertion into the database and store them in a separate table (with a many-to-many relationship). You could then use very simple SQL queries to find the most used hashtags.

Comment: I've decided to go with this route by creating a second table called hashtags with fields 'hashtag' and 'messageid' that would reference the messages table. What SQL query would give me the most frequently mentioned hashtags?

Answer (score 0):

Do not take me wrongly, but you've set up yourself for *a world of hurt*. The best way to proceed would be to **follow lonesomeday's advice** and parse hashtags at insert time. This also greatly reduces processing time as well as making it more deterministic (the workload is "spread" between inserts).

If you want to proceed anyway, you need to tackle several problems.

1) Recognize the tags.

2) Multiple-select the tags. If you have a message saying that "#MySQL splitting is #cool", you want to get **two** rows from that one message, one saying 'MySQL', the other 'cool'.

3) Selecting the appropriate messages

4) *Performances*

You can approach this in at least two ways. You can use a **stored function** , which you find [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql) (actually from [this site](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/)) - you will have to modify it though.

This syntax will get you the first occurrence of #hashtag in `value` *plus all the text following it*:

```
select substring(value, LENGTH(substring_index(value, '#', 1))+1);
```

You will then need to decide where, for each #hashtag, it #stops. (And it could be #parenthesized). At this point you need a regexp, or to search for a sequence of at least one alphanumeric character - in regexp parlance, `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - by specifying all possible characters or by using a loop, i.e. "#" is OK, "#t" is OK, "#ta" is OK, "#tag" is OK, "#tag," is not and so your hashtag is '#tag' (or 'tag').

Another more promising approach is to use a **user defined function** to capture the hashtags; you can use [`PREG_CAPTURE`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme).

You will probably have to merge both approaches: modifying the stored function's setup and inner loop to read

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT messages.messagetext
                                 FROM messages
                                 WHERE messages.messagetext LIKE '%#%';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2( hashtag` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

) ENGINE=Memory;

```
...

SET occurrence = (SELECT LENGTH(msgtext)
                     - LENGTH(REPLACE(msgtext, '#, ''))
                     +1);
SET i=1;
WHILE i <= occurrence DO
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES SELECT PREG_CAPTURE('/#([a-z0-9]+)/i', messagetext, occurrence));
  SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;
...
```

This will return a list of message-ids and hashtags. You then need to `GROUP` them `BY` hashtag, count them and `ORDER` by count `DESC`, finally adding `LIMIT 5` to only get the five most popular.