# MySQL - Split String

Tags: mysql

My question is similar to this post:
["Reverse GROUP_CONCAT" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql)

However, instead of reverse the `group_concat`, is there a way to split out the string into its own column like this:

```
  id | colors1      | color 2      | color 3 | color 4
+----+-----------------------------+---------+----------
| 1  | Red          | Green        | Blue    | Black
| 2  | Orangered    | Periwinkle   | Black   |
| 3  | Orange       | Black        |         |
```

I also looked into this post:
[How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

But I could not figure out how to get the output I need.

Comment: do you have 4 color in concatenated field or may be more or less?

Comment: there can be 4 or less colors for each id, the max number of color an id has is 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be the query you look for:

First table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE color (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col_type varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO color (col_type)
  VALUES(
         'GREEN,RED,BLACK'
);

SELECT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_type, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS first_color,
        If(  length(col_type) - length(replace(col_type, ',', ''))>1,  
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_type, ',', 2), ',', -1) ,NULL) 
               as second_color,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_type, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS last_color
FROM color
```

the result is as 
**first_color  |  second_color  | third_color**
   GREEN   | RED |BLACK 
fiddle [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48e97/1)

But for more than 3 color and each color in its own order i think the bellow query is the right one.

```
SELECT
   COLOR,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLOR, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS first_color,
   If(  length(COLOR) - length(replace(COLOR, ',', ''))>=1,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLOR, ',', 2), ',', -1) ,NULL) 
       as second_color,
   If(  length(COLOR) - length(replace(COLOR, ',', ''))>=2,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLOR, ',', 3), ',', -1) ,NULL) 
       AS third_color,
   If(  length(COLOR) - length(replace(COLOR, ',', ''))>=3,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLOR, ',', 4), ',', -1) ,NULL) 
       AS fourth_color
FROM COLOR;
```

to know the max number of concatenation occurred in COLOR field you can do

```
select (length(COLOR) - length(replace(COLOR, ',', '')) as NumColors
```

Then use loop to make the if section of query according to the max number of colors in table.
fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90e6a/16)

Comment: When I test this on my data set, this is what happened: for the ones have only 1 color --> first and third columns are filled with same value, 2nd column null; for the ones that have 2 colors --> first column filled with first color, 2nd column null, 3rd col filled with 2nd color; for the ones that have 3 colors, worked correctly. I will add a fiddle link shortly to replicate.

Comment: I dont know how to select the 4th color

Comment: @PerriMa i modified the query to bring the result as you want.