# FIND_IN_SET for part of string in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, find-in-set

I need to make a query to a table in my database. Until now I was using `FIND_IN_SET` because I have strings like this: *"twitter,bycicle,car"*.

Then, I could search by `FIND_IN_SET("twitter", nameOfColumn)`

But now, I need to search just part of each "set", for example: *"twitter>10,bycicle,car"*

It still works fine for bycicle and car but if I need to search for twitter, I cannot find it. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you have another symbol( not comma ) inside string so `FIND_IN_SET()` don't work, instead you can use from `substring_index`.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748845/mysql-split-string/26750049#26750049) is the same problem that i answered in the past, may help u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query would give you what you want, however use it with caution with respect to the data you have:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE col1 RLIKE 'twitter'
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66f538/1

Comment: I didn't want to use LIKE because of that, maybe there are some similar strings and it make confusion. If I have no other way, I will use it

Comment: @Biribu to slightly improve it, you may also try this: `RLIKE 'twitter.*,?'`

Comment: I have problems with words shorter than the contained in db. If I try with "twit", I get in return the row...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**LIKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE nameOfColumn LIKE '%twitter%';
```