# MySql parse, split in several rows without knowing the number of divitions

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now. I'm working migrating options from tableA to tableB:
    `tableA`

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ id_skills ║ skills       ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ Java, Python ║
║ 2         ║ JavaScript   ║
║ 3         ║ Ruby, Java   ║
║ 4         ║ Python, C#   ║
║ 5         ║ C++, Ruby    ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

`tableB`

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id_skills ║ skills     ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1         ║ Java       ║
║ 2         ║ JavaScript ║
║ 3         ║ Ruby       ║
║ 4         ║ C#         ║
║ 5         ║ C++        ║
║ 6         ║ Python     ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I was trying to find a function of sql, that unconcat a string
and is necessary to create everything in a script 
We don't really know how many "," is going to be in each row.
Example: 
`"Java, Python"`
In this case, into two rows:
-> Java
-> Python

`Note:`There isn't a function of MySql that split a string

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Reverse GROUP\_CONCAT" in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a query using `substring_index()`, if you know the maximum number of possible values in a string:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id_skills,
       substring_index(substring_index(a.skills, ', ', n.n), ', ', -1) as skill
from tableA a join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n
     on n.n <= 1 + length(a.skills) - length(replace(a.skills, ',', '') cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

You just need to be sure you have enough values in the `n` subquery.

Comment: Very straightforward way to do it. Thank you so much