# Find greatest value of defined string in MySQL from a particular field (separated by comma)

Tags: mysql, sql

We need to get the row, which has value in `cmts` greater than given value`(4000)`, below is our example table structure

`id cmts
 1  1000,2000,3000,4000
 2  1100,2200,3300,4400`

Output should be the 2nd row(ID 2).

Comment: Does the cmts filed always contains comma separated sorted values? if yes just get index of last comma, get substring for the last number, convert the number and compare with 4000. If it's bigger the row must be included into the results

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql

Comment: @StanislavL, Yes the cmts field will always separated by comma

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) And [ask] <- Do read it pls. Or how much do you plan to pay to do your job?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM cmts
WHERE CONVERT(SUBSTR(cmts, SUBSTRING_INDEX(cmts,',',-1), LEN(cmts)), ,UNSIGNED INTEGER)>4000
```