# MySQL get string(s) between two # / multiple pairs of #

Tags: php, mysql

How can I find string between two # or multiple pairs of #.

An example text to search:
This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk before coming home#.

I want results to be:

important

milk before coming home

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
<?php
    $s =  'This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk before coming home#';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++)
        if($s[$i] == "#") {
        $i++;
        $str="";
        while($s[$i]!='#') {
            echo $s[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        echo '<br>';
    };
    ?>
```

then you will get your result

important

milk before coming home

Comment: But how can I do it directly with MySQL query?

Comment: After you get your sql statement executed, loop over the result and do the same previous code

Comment: I'll probably just get the whole stuff from database and use php to parse it and get what I want, thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Edit 1

```
create table t91
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(1000) not null
);
insert t91(thing) values
('This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk before coming home#'),
('This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk home#'),
('This is #');


select id,thing,theCount
from
(   SELECT id,thing,
        ROUND (   
            (
                LENGTH(thing)
                - LENGTH( REPLACE ( thing, "#", "") ) 
            ) / LENGTH("#")        
        ) AS theCount    
    FROM t91
) d
where d.theCount>1
-- 2 rows returned (id 1 and 2)
```

The above Edit used a strategy poached from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344881)

### Edit2

```
-- truncate table t91;
create table t91
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(1000) not null
);
insert t91(thing) values
('This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk before coming home#'),
('This is #important# and needs to elaborated further. Remember to buy #milk home#'),
('This is #'),
('This is #1# ... #2# ... #');
```

Function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS findInsideHashMarks;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION findInsideHashMarks(s VARCHAR(200),segments INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i,nextPos,i1,i2 INT;
    DECLARE sOut VARCHAR(200);
    SET i=0;
    SET nextPos=1;
    SET sOut='';
    WHILE i<segments DO
        -- LOCATE(substr,str,pos)
        SET i1=LOCATE('#',s,nextPos);
        IF i1>0 THEN
            SET i1=i1+1;
            SET nextPos=i1+1;
            SET i2=LOCATE('#',s,nextPos);
            IF i2>0 THEN
                SET nextPos=i2+1;
                SET i2=i2-1;
                SET sOut=CONCAT(sOut,SUBSTRING(s,i1,i2-i1+1));
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i=i+1;
        IF i<segments THEN
            SET sOut=CONCAT(sOut,',');
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN sOut;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Query:

```
SELECT id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(segString, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) dummy
FROM
(   select id,thing,theCount,cast(floor(theCount / 2) as unsigned) as segments,
    findInsideHashMarks(thing,cast(floor(theCount / 2) as unsigned)) as segString
    FROM
    (   SELECT id,thing,
            ROUND (   
                (   LENGTH(thing)
                    - LENGTH( REPLACE ( thing, "#", "") ) 
                ) / LENGTH("#")        
            ) AS theCount    
        FROM t91
    ) d1
    where d1.theCount>1
) d2
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
ON LENGTH(REPLACE(d2.segString, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(d2.segString)-n.digit
ORDER BY d2.id,n.digit;
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id | dummy                   |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | important               |
|  1 | milk before coming home |
|  2 | important               |
|  2 | milk home               |
|  4 | 1                       |
|  4 | 2                       |
+----+-------------------------+
```

The digits breakout of a set (a,b,c) to rows was inspired (understatement) by this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308737) from User [fthiella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833073/fthiella). As noted in that Answer from fthiella (or not expressly so), the `UNION` strategy could be expanded to pick up, say, 10 or more chunks of data between `#` markers.

Also note the prior attribution at the bottom of Edit1.

### Edit3

An offshoot off of Edit2's function and query, but using a permanent Helper Table to avoid the `UNION` in the query for derived table `n`. It supports up to 100 `#` segments. Uses the prior (Edit2) t91 table and the Function.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE 4kTable
(   -- a helper table of about 4k consecutive ints
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing int null
)engine=MyISAM;

insert 4kTable (thing) values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
insert 4kTable (thing) select thing from 4kTable;
-- verify:
-- select min(id),max(id),count(*) from 4kTable;
-- 1 4608 4608

ALTER TABLE 4kTable ENGINE = InnoDB; -- *********** it is now InnoDB

-- verify:
-- select min(id),max(id),count(*) from 4kTable;
-- 1 4608 4608
-- no innodb auto_increment gaps (consecutive block)
```

Query:

```
SELECT id, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(segString, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) dummy 
FROM 
(   select d1.id,thing,theCount,cast(floor(theCount / 2) as unsigned) as segments, 
    findInsideHashMarks(thing,cast(floor(theCount / 2) as unsigned)) as segString 
    FROM 
    (   SELECT id,thing, 
            ROUND (   
                (   LENGTH(thing) 
                    - LENGTH( REPLACE ( thing, "#", "") )  
                ) / LENGTH("#")         
            ) AS theCount     
        FROM t91 
    ) d1 
    where d1.theCount>1 
) d2 
INNER JOIN
(select id-1 as digit from 4kTable where id<=100) n
ON LENGTH(REPLACE(d2.segString, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(d2.segString)-n.digit
ORDER BY d2.id,n.digit;
```

Same output as above Edit2 `Output` section. I usually have a few permanent Helper Tables in a system, especially for `left joins` with dates.

Comment: But what if you just know you need find something between #...# and you do not know what?

Comment: Oh then scrap this idea

Comment: See Edit at bottom

Comment: @Drew why don't you use [`CHAR_LENGTH(str)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel cuz I am in the middle of a lot of stuff and sought a solution :p

Comment: Sorry guys but don't get it. I have table called Event and column called  description in there. I need to find all occurrences (strings) which are delimited by #....# from the description. # in the beginning and # at the end of the string. Example text is just one row (description) in the table. So I want 2 rows as a result "important" and  "milk before coming home". Sorry for being so vague in the first place...

Comment: well load up my t91 and run the query. Two out of the 3 rows qualify with a `# ...#` thing. Determine if you can accept a stored proc solution. It would take the (count mod 2) and know the segment count. And loop. Also, how would call the proc with parameters. Devil's in the details.

Comment: I tried it, thanks. It is not exactly what I'm looking for though... I guess I need some more trial and error  + reading some documentation.

Comment: Here's a working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7415f/5) with CHAR_LENGTH(). BTW: Nice trick using MyISAM for the sequence table.