# mysql char displaying just the first character

Tags: mysql, select, char, ascii

I have this value in my MYSQL table "&#84&#101&#115&#116 "    (=="Test")
this text is basically in decimal format.
more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T#Computing_codes
i am trying to run a select query as its a regular text.
these are the tests i'm running:

1.
query:
select TRIM(Leading ',' FROM replace(trim(name),"&#",","))  from table where id = 1;

output:
84,101,115,116

2.
query:
select char(84,101,115,116);

output: Test

3.
query:
select char(TRIM(Leading ',' FROM replace(trim(name),"&#",","))) from table where id = 1;

output: T

How can i get the whole word instead of just the first character?

Thanks,

Nir.

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting  expected result because

```
TRIM(Leading ',' FROM replace(trim(name),"&#",","))
```

returns string instead of array

```
'84,101,115,116'
```

Then *char()* only interprets first readable set of numbers.

If you want to continue, take a look at similar question made with [procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql).

You should create a procedure that would return string decimals as a table result set and then use it as input to your *CHAR()*. This way you would move complicated logic to procedure and then use it like this (untested):

```
select
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        SELECT
            char(*)
        FROM
            (
                CALL database.getDecimalText()
            )
    ) SEPARATOR '' )
from
    table
    where
        id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Mulcek, your passing what looks like comma separated arguments to the `CHAR` function, but this is in fact a single string that contains commas. MySQL interprets it as such and returns the decoded first number it recognises.

A one step solution would be to use a prepared statement to build the whole query as a string and then execute that as follows:

```
SET @VTestVar = '&#84&#101&#115&#116';
SET @VExec = CONCAT('SELECT CHAR(', (SELECT TRIM(Leading ',' FROM REPLACE(TRIM(@VTestVar),"&#",","))), ') value;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @VExec;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here it is adjusted for your use case:

```
SET @VTestVar = '&#84&#101&#115&#116';
SET @VExec = CONCAT('SELECT CHAR(', (SELECT TRIM(Leading ',' FROM REPLACE(TRIM(select TRIM(Leading ',' FROM replace(trim(name),"&#",",")) from table where id = 1),"&#",","))), ') value;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @VExec;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Regards,

James