# MYSQL view containing a row for each element in string

Tags: mysql

I don't know if it's possible but I try to ask you.
I've a user table

```
|ID|production_lines|activity|
|1 |    A|B|C       | X|Y|Z  |
|2 |    B|C|D       | X|Y|Z  |
```

I need a view displaying this

```
|production_line|activity|count|
|    A          | X      | 1   |
|    B          | X      | 2   |
|    C          | X      | 2   |
|    D          | X      | 1   |
|    A          | Y      | 1   |
|    B          | Y      | 2   |
|    C          | Y      | 2   |
|    D          | Y      | 1   |
```

and so on...
The "count" columns is the count of how many time i've a combination of this particular production_line and activity.

Thank you very much

Comment: Clearly a bad table design.  Look into this for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql

Comment: You should normalise your data structure

Comment: your desired view looks like how the table should be probably be structured in the first place.

Comment: I know... I can't do a refactor of this table. I'll do somehting in PHP.