# Split comma separated string into rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I have string list like 1, 2, 3...
I'd like to use this as one column

```
Ids
1
2
3
```

Is it possible by sql query?

ex) `SELECT Ids from (1, 2, 3...)`   <- I know this is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the opposite of GROUP\_CONCAT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/what-is-the-opposite-of-group-concat-in-mysql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a subquery of arbitrary digits to split your string.Instead of vals you can use '1,2,3'.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(vals, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) val
FROM
  tt1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(vals, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(vals)-n.digit;
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/CHEUQI16268)

Comment: Sorry but I have something to ask. If the length of string is not fixed, is it possible to convert?

Comment: Very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669#17308737).

Answer (score 11):

For MySQL 8.0.4+

```
SELECT *
FROM
  JSON_TABLE(
          CONCAT('[', '1,2,3,4', ']'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS tt
```

Concatenate square brackets (`[]`) around your string to make it into a JSON array. Then use `JSON_TABLE` to convert it into a table. See the [MySQL JSON Table Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below stored procedure to split string delimted by any character:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `split_delimited` (
IN inputstr NVARCHAR(1000),
IN delimiter CHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE Items;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Items(item NVARCHAR(50)); 
WHILE LOCATE(delimiter,inputstr) > 1 DO
INSERT INTO Items SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputstr,delimiter,1);
SET inputstr = REPLACE (inputstr, (SELECT LEFT(inputstr,LOCATE(delimiter,inputstr))),'');
END WHILE;
INSERT INTO Items(item) VALUES(inputstr);
select * from Items;
END
```

Input: 'a,b,c'
Output: a
b
c

Answer (score 0):

Note, this answer is probably not compatible with the released versions of MySQL available at the time the question was asked. I added it for future references for those interested in using a recursive CTE approach. Furthermore, irregular data have been added to test the exception handling.

```
create table test(ids varchar(50));
insert test values('1,2,3');

-- Note: the next_start_pos is the position to the immediate right of the comma.

with recursive cte as
    (select locate(',',ids,1)+1 as next_start_pos,
    substring(ids,1,locate(',',ids,1)-1) as i
    from test 
    union
    select locate(',',t.ids,next_start_pos)+1 ,
    case when locate(',',t.ids,next_start_pos) !=0 then substring(t.ids,next_start_pos,locate(',',t.ids,next_start_pos)-next_start_pos)
    else  substring(t.ids,next_start_pos) end 
    from test t join cte c
    where next_start_pos!=1
    )
select next_start_pos, i from cte where i !='';

+----------------+------+
| next_start_pos | i    |
+----------------+------+
|              3 | 1    |
|              5 | 2    |
|              1 | 3    |
+----------------+------+
```

Note, in the main query which queries the cte result table, the `where i !=''` should be included as a foolproof feature. It circumvents result of empty space caused by leading/trailing comma or consecutive comma. Take the case below for instance:

```
truncate test;
insert test values(',,,1,,2,3,,,,'); 

-- run the same query again and we get:
+----------------+------+
| next_start_pos | i    |
+----------------+------+
|              6 | 1    |
|              9 | 2    |
|             11 | 3    |
+----------------+------+

-- if the WHERE clause is removed, then we get:
+----------------+------+
| next_start_pos | i    |
+----------------+------+
|              2 |      |
|              3 |      |
|              4 |      |
|              6 | 1    |
|              7 |      |
|              9 | 2    |
|             11 | 3    |
|             12 |      |
|             13 |      |
|             14 |      |
|              1 |      |
+----------------+------+
```