# MYSQL function (or combined query) that allows me to supplied string and search a comma delimited field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am looking for a way to supply a string and query it against a column that has delimited values in it. Its kinds the opposite of the FIND_IN_SET command.

For example. I have a this string "The Dog Jumps High". In my table, I have comma delimited values such as "Dog Walks, Dog Jumps, Cat Jumps, Cat Walks". These delimited values are spread between thousands of rows.

I would like a query that takes the string, and find the comma delimited value that is part of the string, and return that specific record.

What i don't want to do is download the entire DB and run it through a script, I am looking to see if i can accomplishes this in MYSQL. In addition, I am using the Laravel framework, so if theres an easy way to do this through eloquent, that would be great as well.

I have searched fairly extensively for an answer, but I don't think i am searching right as all the results being back FIND_IN_SET and that will not work (from my knowledge) for this use case.

Comment: Your primary issue is storing serialized lists in a single field and needing to use individual items in a query context. You need to normalize those lists into a separate linked table that can be effectively queried.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what your use case is ... in general this sounds like it could be handled so much better with a better design. But as stated (jumping dogs) it is hard to know if it is a real world problem or an academic question.

Comment: The only solution in SQL is to convert your comma-separated list to an array and explode it with `JSON_TABLE()`, then join that to your string. It's terribly poor efficiency. I agree that storing the data in a normalized manner would be better.

Comment: On the other hand, searching for substring matches is always going to be difficult to make efficient in SQL. The issue with comma-separated lists is a red herring.

Comment: For the record, the old post we're referring to is: [Is storing a delimited list in a database really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).

Comment: Have a look at FTS (Full-Text-Search) solutions like Apache Lucene - essentially that type of solution indexes your text fields and allows you to do more advanced queries...

Comment: I agree that closing the question as duplicate was not particularly helpful, and that the referenced question was really only _tangentially_ applicable. That said, the alternative would be [splitting the serialized data into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919730/split-comma-separated-string-into-rows-in-mysql) in a subquery/view and then using it downstream as if it were properly normalized, performing much more poorly than the "don't do it that way" alternative but still technically working.

Comment: Your reason you cannot find a solution after searching extensively is because your are trying to solve an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329)".  Essentially, you are trying to solve a problem that you shouldn't be encountering.  You are only going to give yourself future headaches if you continue to operate within this suboptimal design structure.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574), the ideal situation is having the data normalized out into individual rows which would let you do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM doublets d INNER JOIN linking_table l
  ON d.id = l.doublet_id
  INNER JOIN parent p
  ON l.parent_id = p.id
WHERE 'The quick Dog Jumps over the lazy fox' LIKE CONCAT('%', d.value, '%');
```

but that would potentially require a lot of code changes to accommodate the new schema.

You can also use [custom stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919730/split-comma-separated-string-into-rows-in-mysql) to dynamically split the serialized data into individual rows that can be used the same way, but that's a lot of extra string functions dragging down the performance of every query.

You can, however, migrate more gradually, accommodating the current query needs without immediately breaking code reliant on the current schema. You would need to perform something like the following migration:

1. Rename the current `parent` table to something like `parent_new`.
2. Create the `doublets` and `linking_table` tables like below.
3. Run a migration [likely in PHP] that populates these tables.
4. Drop the `doublets` column from `parent_new`.
5. Create a new view named `parent` that re-creates the expected prior structure.

The end result being something like:

```
CREATE TABLE doublets (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO doublets (value) VALUES
  ('Dog Walks'),
  ('Dog Jumps'),
  ('Cat Jumps'),
  ('Cat Walks');

CREATE TABLE parent_new (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO parent_new (value) VALUES 
  ('a'), ('b');

CREATE TABLE linking_table (
  parent_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  doublet_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY( parent_id, doublet_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent_new(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (doublet_id) REFERENCES doublets(id)
);

INSERT INTO linking_table (parent_id, doublet_id) VALUES
  (1, 1), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4);

CREATE VIEW parent AS
  SELECT
      p.*,
      GROUP_CONCAT(d.value) 'doublets'
  FROM doublets d INNER JOIN linking_table l
    ON d.id = l.doublet_id
    INNER JOIN parent_new p
    ON l.parent_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id;

SELECT * FROM parent;
```

Where:

```
SELECT *
FROM doublets d INNER JOIN linking_table l
  ON d.id = l.doublet_id
  INNER JOIN parent_new p
  ON l.parent_id = p.id
WHERE 'The quick Dog Jumps over the lazy fox' LIKE CONCAT('%', d.value, '%');
```

yields:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+----+-------+
| id | value     | parent_id | doublet_id | id | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+----+-------+
| 2  | Dog Jumps |         1 |          2 |  1 |     a |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+----+-------+
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM parent;
```

yields:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id |     value |            doublets |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |         a | Dog Walks,Dog Jumps |
|  2 |         b | Cat Jumps,Cat Walks |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

In this way you can have queries leverage the new, more efficient structure via `parent_new` while legacy code still hits the `parent` view. Just be sure to eventually catch up on this technical debt and change over the rest of the queries to the new structure, otherwise you risk accumulating a precarious stack of views under otherwise simple and innocent looking queries.