# Count entries grouped by id and month from denormalized database

Tags: php, mysql, grouping, counting, denormalized

I have a table (tbl_operations) with rows of where the id column values may be comma-delimited.  I want to get the count of each `OpId` for each month. I am trying to accomplish this through pure sql, but without success.

**from this view**

| OpId | OpDate |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 |
| 5,3 | 2022-01-15 |
| 4 | 2022-01-27 |
| 5 | 2022-02-01 |
| 7 | 2022-02-09 |
| 3,2 | 2022-01-16 |

**to this**

| OpId | count | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 01 |
| 3 | 3 | 01 |
| 4 | 1 | 01 |
| 5 | 1 | 01 |
| 5 | 1 | 02 |
| 7 | 1 | 02 |

I am stuck here. Can someone enlighten me on how to do this with sql? If not, maybe use php to display the result?

```
SELECT tbl_operations.OpId,
    tbl_operations.OpDate ,
    COUNT(tbl_operations.OpId) AS `count`
FROM tbl_operations
WHERE MONTH(OpDate)=1
GROUP BY  tbl_operations.OpId
```

Comment: Do you have arrays, or do you have a text field with numbers and sometimes commas? Also, you might be _calling_ this from PHP, but are you looking for a MySQL-only solution?

Comment: Hi Chris, its a text field. the result matters, doesnt matter php or mysql

Comment: I think what Chris was asking was "can there be more than one value of OpID in that same field?" There should not really be multiple comma-separated values in a single column as it makes stuff like this more complex.

Comment: Is there a typo in your desired results? You show opid 5 as having one entry for month two, twice. Should that be once for month 1, and once for month 2?

Comment: no only one id per row. 
2,3,4 or 6,7,8,9

Comment: @droopsnoot yes sorry for that. my mistake

Comment: I say spend the time normalizing your db structure so that this is a sim0le sql task instead of fiddling with php to do the grouping/summing/prep.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes thats the best solution. Thank you all

Comment: [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246701/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a quick example. The first part just creates an array of arrays which simulates what you’d get from the database.

The gist is that `$counts` is an array with a unique OpID for a keys. The values for those arrays are sub-arrays with keys of the month and values of how many times they are found.

Display should just be a simple loop again, however you might want to sort this.

```php
$rows = [
['3',   '2022-01-03'],
['5,3', '2022-01-15'],
['4',   '2022-01-27'],
['5',   '2022-02-01'],
['7',   '2022-02-09'],
['3,2', '2022-01-16'],
];

$counts = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $ids = explode(',', $row[0]);
    $month = date('m', strtotime($row[1]));
    foreach($ids as $id){
        if(!array_key_exists($id, $counts)){
            $counts[$id] = [];
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($month, $counts[$id])){
            $counts[$id][$month] = 0;
        }
        
        $counts[$id][$month]++;
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/mVaBB

**edit**

From @mickmackusa, you can shorten the inner loop by using `isset`:

```php
        if(!isset($counts[$id][$month])){
            $counts[$id][$month] = 0;
        }
```

See their comment for a demo link

Comment: Parent level arrays need not be declared. You can safely omit `if(!array_key_exists($id, $counts)){
            $counts[$id] = [];
        }`.

Comment: @mickmackusa, you sure about that? https://3v4l.org/NDIYB I’m running on not enough coffee, so I might be missing something

Comment: `isset()` is better for this task. https://3v4l.org/KlrhY

Comment: Thanks, updated with your version, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas & mickmackusa thank you both guys

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to query the data in PHP, you might as well return a better result to work with in the first place:

**SQL**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(OpId), MONTH(OpDate)
FROM tbl_operations
GROUP BY MONTH(OpDate)
```

**PHP**

```
// Result from MySQL query
$rows = [
    ['3,5,3,4,3,2', 1],
    ['5,7', 2]
];
```

And you can perform a count of those grouped results like this:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $counts = array_count_values(explode(',', $row[0]));
    $results[$row[1]] = $counts;
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [5] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [5] => 1
            [7] => 1
        )

)
```

---

What you really want to do though is normalise your data, then you can do this easily in SQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using at least MYSQL8 and you are not going to normalize your table design, then you can actually use the following [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/) query to split, group, format, and sort your result set (no PHP processing).

This approach makes recursive calls on the denormalized table and progressively isolates the rightmost id from comma-delimited values and generates new rows for the individual id values. The recursion continues until there are no commas left.

This solution is built on top of the basic technique [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67726962/2943403).

SQL: ([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17fdee2e87a18b3341d345d0ce73bf06))

```
WITH RECURSIVE norm AS (
    SELECT OpId,
           OpDate
    FROM tbl_operations
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(OpId, '^[^,]*,', '') AS OpId,
           OpDate
    FROM norm
    WHERE OpId LIKE '%,%'
)
SELECT Id,
       Mo,
       COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(norm.OpId, ',.*', '') AS Id,
           MONTH(norm.OpDate) AS Mo
    FROM norm
) formatted
GROUP BY formatted.Id, 
         formatted.Mo
```

Result Set:

| Id | Mo | Cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 |

That said, this is a lot of unnecessary voodoo mumbo jumbo for a task that is mega-easy once you've normalized your table --- just normalize it A.S.A.P.

Comment: Thank you, the table have been normalized .