# Error 1064# While using mysql Like keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, sql-like

my sql query is:

```
mysql> select emp_id where classes like '%'XII'%';
```

but i am getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where classes like '%'XII'%'' at line 1

I can understand that error is due to single quotes i have used in like arguments but i have string say 'X','XI','XII' in my database. that's why i am querying with single quote because if i query for class X in String 'XI','XII' then it will return emp_id of those who are teaching XI and XII standard which is undesirable.

Can i use escape characters for special characters in like argument.

Comment: You forgot `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape a single quote (`'`) by doubling it (`''`):

```
select emp_id FROM my_table where classes like '%''XII''%';
```

Note: These are two single quotes, not a double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use double qoutes to enclose search pattern

```
select emp_id from tableName 
where classes like "%'XII'%";
```

Please dont store values as comma seprated strings , this is not a good database design practice. [**See why here , esp Lasse V. Karlsen answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738133/comma-separated-values-in-a-database-field)

So instead of

```
empid   classes
1       'X','XI','XII'
```

store this as separate rows

```
empid   classes
1       'X'
1       'XI'
1       'XII'
```