# How to put array into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i have an array

```
variable $smt_database = 257, 259, 261

Array ( [0] => 257, 259, 261 )
```

how can i insert this variable $smt_database in database like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE member_id IN ($smt_database)";
```

when i echo the sql it show array like below :

```
SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE member_id IN (Array)
```

how can i change so it can like sql below :

```
SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE member_id IN (257, 259, 261)
```

i know we must use implode and explode but i do not know how to implement them.

Comment: Where does the `$smt_database` variable come from? Is it user supplied data?

Comment: it from database.. but i have the answer already thanks.

Comment: You store comma separated data in your columns? That's a SQL anti-pattern ... besides that, you can just use `${stm_database[0]}`.

Comment: yes.. hehe.. i dunno anti pattern.. i saw one of the answer below.. nice approach.. i never though of that

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738133/comma-separated-values-in-a-database-field) for more information on "Jaywalking" anti-pattern.

Comment: @airi If you got answer from following answer then accept it for future reference

Comment: @Sadikhasan FYI .. i need to wait 10 minute to accept any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple use `implode`

```
$in_text = implode(",", $smt_database);

// now use this variable in sql like

$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE member_id IN ($in_text)";
```

above will work if the values in array are numeric

So if value in array are not numeric you need to single quotes on your value try

**update 2 :**

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $val)
{
    $new_array[] = "'".$val."'";
}

// now use implode

 $in_text = implode(",", $new_array);

  // now use this variable in sql
```

Comment: implode is useless for `Array ( [0] => 257, 259, 261 )` its useful for `Array ( [0] => 257,[1]=> 259,[2]=> 261 )`

Comment: thanks .. i just missing the implode .. $mid1 = implode(',', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $smt_database));

Answer (score 1):

Use with `impload` and `FIND_IN_SET` because `IN` operator do not work on String value.

```
$your_text = implode(",",$smt_database);

$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE FIND_IN_SET(member_id,$your_text)";
```

Comment: bro `,` is missing in `implode`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members 'WHERE member_id IN (".$smt_database[0].")";
```

*assuming you have array* `$smt_database = Array ( [0] => 257, 259, 261 )`

Comment: hi nice way to solve my problems.. thanks for the knowledge sharing.. never thought the way of solving this kind of problems like this..